# Meaning of "over one day"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

> "I read 192 pages in French, in just two sittings ***over one day*** .
>   "

What does "over one day" mean  here?

Comment: What is it that you're actually questioning? It means *within a period of one day.* But that may not be the source of your confusion. Whether it means 24 hours or the time the sun was up is ambiguous.

Comment: The writer is saying that two sessions happened on a single day.

Comment: @Ring So "over" is exactly the same as "on" here?

Comment: "over" is short for "Over the course of" and means the same as "during" in this construction. It emphasizes the  period of time elapsed, and is more often used for times longer than a single day, although it can be used for a day. Note the similar sounding "I worked for over a day to read 192 pages" which means that **more** than a day was spent, although probably less than two days.

Comment: It is in this context. Refer to @DavidSiegel's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the phrase "over one day" means "over the course of/duration of a single day." In particular, both sittings wherein the person referring to him or herself as "I" in the sentence read the 192 pages in French occurred on the same day.